# how to change the font type of a newcommand in latex?

Tags: latex

i have this thingy
\newcommand{\ru}{$\mathrm{Ru(NH_3)Cl_6};$}
, which is a chemical fomula, normally it should be normal font

but since my captions are italic(\usepackage[format=plain,labelfont={bf,it},textfont=it, font=small]{caption})
so when it is used in the captions it is expected to be italic as well, but it is not. is there a smart way to do this?

Many thanks!!!

expecting a way to make one \newcommand which is normal in the normal context and italic in the caption.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing is to use a specific chemistry package like [chemsym](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemsym) with `\usepackage{chemsym}`. ‘CH3’ is obtained by typing ‘\CH_3’ in your LaTeX document. See the [documentation](https://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chemsym/chemsym.pdf).

There are also other packages available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry).